# Expression Engine admin page redirects to index view

Tags: redirects

I am a newbie to Expression Engine, and am trying to help a local nonprofit with an EE site that was hacked. The details of the hack are unclear.

Their admin page was at a specific URL which now no longer renders the administrative login page. Instead, it renders the site's "home" page (root path.)

Specifically, `/main`, the admin page, redirects to `/main/index.php`, which then renders the same content as '/' would have.

My question is - where would you advise me to look for the start of the redirect chain, or to figure out why `main/index.php` simply renders what `/index.php` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with looking at the `index.php` file in the `/main` directory.

Open it up to verify it's contents. Is it the same as the `index.php` file for the home page/root of the website? If so, you need to simply find the original `admin.php` file for that install or download another one. Next, rename the `admin.php` file from `admin.php` to `index.php` and move it into the `/main` folder.

Make sure you remap the `/system` folder relative path in the new `/main/index.php` file.